# Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_intel_thread.1.dylib

Tags: pyinstaller, intel-mkl, py2app

I am trying to take my code and turn it into a Mac application. I have tried using PYinstaller and PY2app. However, the application that I made with both had an issue where It would make the program but it could not load libmkl_intel_thread.1.dylib when running the program. I have tried downloading a mlk and other things. I am using anaconda but its running on a Mac virtual machine on my windows computer. Additionally I am using PYsimpleGUI as the gui for my program and openpyxl. I should note that the code references an excel document (if that is the issue on a mac then please let me know, this is my first time working with them).
Anyway help with this would be greatly appreciated because I am very stuck and a bit of a novice.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out this article:
https://www.l3harrisgeospatial.com/Support/Self-Help-Tools/Help-Articles/Help-Articles-Detail/ArtMID/10220/ArticleID/24118/Workaround-when-IDL-to-python-bridge-is-crashing-due-to-MKL-library-conflict

I used this to great success running Mac OS Monterey on a virtualbox VM to package and launch an application for both windows and macos. You will have to reinstall the MKL libraries that this solution removes before continuing, so remember to use

conda install openpyxl

to prevent a crash after re-running pyinstaller on the source file. PySimpleGUI doesn't seem to be affected by this change.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it worked. I had tried using nomkl before, but I didn't uninstall mkl before I installed it. But yes this worked great.

Comment: I have the same issue but I'm hesitant to uninstall MKL, which I don't know anything about and might bite me later. Is this really a safe solution?

Answer (score 0):

The method in the article worked perfectly for me, but before doing it use
conda list

and copy the list of installed packages to a text file to compare with the final result.