# Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_intel_thread.dylib. ----- Library not loaded: @rpath/libiomp5.dylib

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pycharm, python-3.7, python-3.10

```
/Users/dozieanazia/.conda/envs/Exercise Files/bin/python" "/Users/dozieanazia/Dropbox/My Mac (Dozie’s MacBook Pro)/Downloads/Ex_Files_Building_Deep_Learning_Apps/Exercise Files/03/create_model.py"
INTEL MKL ERROR: dlopen(/Users/dozieanazia/.conda/envs/Exercise Files/lib/libmkl_intel_thread.dylib, 9): Library not loaded: @rpath/libiomp5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/dozieanazia/.conda/envs/Exercise Files/lib/libmkl_intel_thread.dylib
  Reason: image not found.
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_intel_thread.dylib.
Process finished with exit code 2
```

This was the full error I received. I've scoured StackOverflow for the right answer, but nothing I've inputted has worked. These particulars lessons are from Linkedin Learning course on Keras.

I don't know if it has something to do with my hardware since I'm using a Macbook from 2012.

The interesting thing about it, When I'm in the pre-processing data file, the python environment is in `python 3.10` and it runs(I did have this error until tinkered with it, but finally got it work). When I move to create_model file, this error comes back and now I'm stuck again. Since I'm `Python 3.10`, the whole file has problems. I switch python to `3.7` and now I don't have errors until I run it. This when I get the error listed above.

Please help.

This is the code file below:

```
import pandas as pd

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import *

training_data_df = pd.read_csv("sales_data_training_scaled.csv")

X = training_data_df.drop('total_earnings', axis=1).values
Y = training_data_df[['total_earnings']].values

// Define the model

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=9, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="adam")
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72343334/intel-mkl-fatal-error-cannot-load-libmkl-intel-thread-1-dylib

Comment: Have you checked the link mentioned in the above comment? Also, please use a complete alias name while importing packages from keras as `from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential` and
 `from tensorflow.keras.layers import *` because now keras is integrated with tenorflow and using tensorflow as backed.